# React-Intl: Locale data added to IntlMessageFormat is missing a `pluralRuleFunction`

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-intl

I'm recently use React-Intl for internationalisation in my Multiple Page React App.

I write a component "IntlProviderWithLocal" to add custom locale.

```
import React from 'react'
import {IntlProvider, addLocaleData} from 'react-intl';

import zh_CN from '../../../components/i18n/zh_CN/angular_locale'

export default (props) => {
    const {children, ...last} = props            

    addLocaleData(zh_CN);    
    return (
        <IntlProvider {...last} messages={zh_CN} >
            {children}
        </IntlProvider>
    )
}
```

But i get the Error:

`Error formatting message: "publish.card.preview" for locale: "zh_CN", using default message as fallback`

I set a BreakPoint in `react-intl/lib/index.es.js`, it shows the error throwed by `var formatter = state.getMessageFormat(message, locale, formats)`.

The `formats` is a empty array. Step the function `getMessageFormat`,

```
return function () {
    var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
    var cacheId = getCacheId(args);
    var format = cacheId && cache[cacheId];

    if (!format) {
        format = new (src$es5$$.bind.apply(FormatConstructor, [null].concat(args)))();

        if (cacheId) {
            cache[cacheId] = format;
        }
    }

    return format;
};
```

Finally I get a error `Locale data added to IntlMessageFormat is missing a pluralRuleFunction for :zh_CN` at `format = new (src$es5$$.bind.apply(FormatConstructor, [null].concat(args)))();`.

At this moment, `args` is `["预览", "zh_CN", Object]`, `cacheId` is `"["预览","zh_CN",[]]"` and `format` is `undefined`

Is there a way to add custom locale data correctly

Answer (score 1):

You don't seem to pass your translations to the provider.

`messages={zh_CN}` should be a key value store containing your translations, such as:

```
messages = {
    "publish.card.preview": "Preview"
}
return <IntlProvider {...last} messages={messages} >
    ...
</IntlProvider>
```

Comment: I'm sure zh_CN is a json. I get the translated words in final page. but get the error too. So, I'm confused what happened

Comment: It's just that it is not the same object that you should pass to `addLocaleData` and `IntlProvider`. `IntlProvider` expects the list of all of your translations when `addLocaleData` expects the dictionary of the different locale settings. I don't know if that's why you have your error though.